# How to use TypeGraphQL with tsyringe

Tags: typegraphql, tsyringe

I have a project using [tsyringe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsyringe) and a RESTFul API. Now i should to add a GraphQL API using the [type-graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-graphql) but in our documentation no have some example using it.

Is possiblem to use tsyringe to make DI with TypeGraphQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible! 
Most IOC containers have the `get` function to retrieve an instance of the given class type. `tsyringe` instead have the `resolve` function. 
Therefore, you have to change the `container` option when building the schema to instruct `type-graphql` how to retrieve (*get*) a class instance from a class type:

```
import { container } from 'tsyringe';

const schema = await buildSchema({
  // ...
  container: { get: (cls) => container.resolve(cls) }
});
```